# SPD 2010 Form Action Workflow Problem

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I am having trouble initiating a form action workflow in SPD 2010.

I am trying to save an item to an audit list prior to deleting it. I have selected "Create a List Item" for the action in the workflow. None of the fields are required in the target list. I selected a field and a static value.  However, when I click on the delete link, I get a generic error message in the browser from the hosting site.

PS. The DVWP is on a web part page. The error message directs me to the web part maintenance page where it says that there are no web parts currently associated with this web part zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Rob. I was able to solve the error. Delete the $Pos variable created by SPD 2010 in the automode template. Then, follow the instructions here:

http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2010/06/10/sharepoint-extending-the-dvwp-%e2%80%93-part-9-oops-failed-setting-processor-stylesheet/

The workflow will then work!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Richard - Looking at another recent post of yours (http://www.sharepointoverflow.com/questions/5659/save-item-prior-to-delete) I had an idea that may help.

What you could do is create a custom permission level in SharePoint and assign it to the appropriate users for this list.  The permission level should disallow the ability for the end user to delete items from the list.  Instead you could add a "Delete this item" checkbox to the list to flag an item as deleted.

Then you can create a SPD workflow that runs when an item is modified.  In the workflow, you could check to see if that deleted field is checked.  If so, write an entry to the other list as you mention above, then delete the current item from the list.

I don't know that this will fix the problem you mention above except that now you will not have to use the delete link.